# Sharing Wireless Network Speed

Tags: router, internet-speed, ieee802.1x

I will be moving in with two other roommates (one of which lived there previously) into a house where one (also new to the place) roommate is currently living. We are paying for a **100mbps** connection through our ISP, and the router says that it can support up to a **300mbps** connection. However, the router+modem (it's one of those with both built into the same device, and is one that I bought last year and has been working fine for me since) only has a 2.4GHz wireless signal, which, as a technician from our ISP told the roommate, "only supports up to a 44mbps connection". Now, the roommate wants to purchase a router that has a 5.0GHz band so that they can get a faster speed, although there are relatively thick walls blocking the signal to basically everyone's rooms. They also brought up putting an Ethernet switch upstairs, but don't want to do it because they've heard that "it makes networks work differently", and we're not sure what that means.

The roommate has asserted that the 5.0GHz signal is necessary because "four people on a 44mbps connection means that we each only get 11mbps and waste the other 56mbps that we are paying for", and this is about where my networking knowledge fails me.

In summary, **can the router give each of us a 25mbps connection (blasting at max 44mbps to each of us, in multiple directions)**, or does it **only do 44mbps in total, giving each of us 11mbps connections?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of a (dumb) ethernet switch as a device that turns one ethernet port into many. For example, if you have a router with 5 gigabit ethernet ports and you need 10 ports, if you plug an 8-port gigabit switch into one of the router's ports, you now have 11 ports on the network (4 left of the router and 7 left on the switch). However, all the devices, should they need to communicate with the router (which might mean accessing the Internet or communicating with the other four devices on the router) will share a 1gbps connection. Thus, unless you're using something like VLANs (you'd know it if you were) or doing high speed transfers on your LAN to devices connected to the router, the switch shouldn't make your network "work differently".

If your router is a single-band router (only supports 2.4GHz), then if it says 300mbps, it ought to support a 300mbps physical link. If it's a dual band (has 2.4GHz and 5Ghz), then the *combined* speed is 300mbps, but it sounds like your router only has 2.4GHz. There is a wi-fi standard for 2.4GHz that supports up to 600mbps (see [here](https://www.speedguide.net/faq/what-do-all-those-80211ac-wireless-speeds-mean-431)), but it sounds like your router does not support it.

Wi-fi speeds, per-band (such as "dual band" and "tri-band" routers), are listed a best-case half-duplex signals on a shared medium (radio waves). That is, the best-case sum of speeds for all connected users is the posted speed (in your case, apparently 44mbps). Further note that half of that is allocated to download and half to upload and you'll maybe lose 20% more due to overhead. So you can only actually sum to the posted speed if you're doing both downloading and uploading. Also note that when you have multiple wi-fi devices connected on the same band, weak connections (e.g., through a thick wall) will result in the connection slowing for *all* users.

**Summary:**
If your router says 300mbps, unless the router itself is slow (and not actually able to deliver data to your computer as fast as the physical radio waves allow), if used correctly, you can expect to share around 120mbps of download speeds under *optimal* conditions.